# Prove a function f is uniformly bounded throughout [0, ∞)

Tags: real-analysis

Let f : [0, ∞) → [0, ∞) be a continuous function with f(0) = 0. Show that if $f(t) ≤ 1 +f(t)^3/10 $ for all t ∈ [0, ∞), then f is uniformly bounded throughout [0, ∞)

I am wondering if the function is uniformly bounded since the definition of uniformly bounded is for a set of functions. And Suppose f(t)= any positive large number (like greater than 10), it seems to be always true that $f(t) ≤ 1 + f(t)^3/10 $.
I am also considering if I can prove the function is uniformly continuous to show it is uniformly bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $2 > 1+2^3/10$, which entails that $f$ is never equal to $2$. By IVT, $f$ remains in $[0,2)$ so is bounded.

Comment: It is f(t)≤1+f(t)^3/10, hence f(x) cannot be 2

Comment: That is exactly what I wrote.